# Access SeqIO.index returned dict in multiprocess shared memory

Tags: python, indexing, multiprocessing, biopython

I have a large file (40G) in FASTA format. To speed up the process, I have a parallel step using `pool.map`. First, `SeqIO.index` is used to load the large file's index info to a shared memory (using multiprocessing's Manager).

But when I run the following code, the program crashes sometimes (traceback only traces to `pool.map`), especially when run with many processes. It may succeed if run like 2 processes. But if I directly load all the data (not the index) into memory (uncomment the "m_records2") the program always runs successfully. I think the difference comes from the index part. Any suggestion will be appreciate!!!

```
import sys
import os
from Bio import SeqIO
from subprocess import *
from multiprocessing import Pool, Manager

manager = Manager()
m_records = manager.dict()
#m_records2 = manager.dict()
m_kmers=manager.dict()

def do_operation(seq):
    ##do some operations with m_kmers
    return

def run_check(read_id):
    seq=str(m_records[read_id].seq)
    #seq=m_records2[read_id]
    do_operation(seq)

def check_reads(n_threads):
    read_id_list=list(m_records.keys())
    #print read_id_list
    pool = Pool(n_threads)
    m_rslt=pool.map(run_check, read_id_list)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sf_reads=sys.argv[1]
    n_threads=int(sys.argv[2])
    m_records=SeqIO.index(sf_reads, "fasta")
    # for key in m_records:
    #     m_records2[key]=str(m_records[key].seq)
    check_reads(n_threads)
```

Comment: Does it happen with small files as well or only with your 40G file?

Comment: @MaximilianPeters It happens for small files. I have a test file with 18 long reads, when set for 14 or larger number of processes it will crash when I test.

Comment: I would suggest you include the full traceback in your question - it might give some clues, and/or help people searching with a similar error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could reproduce your problem with a smaller data set (all proteins from E. Coli) and it really does occur randomly.
It seems that the problem is the use of `manager.dict()` on `SeqIO.index` which is a different type.

```
>>> print(type(m_records))
<class 'Bio.File._IndexedSeqFileDict'>
```

From the [documentation](http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/api/Bio.SeqIO-module.html):

> Indexes a sequence file and returns a dictionary like object.

From the [source code](http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/api/Bio.SeqIO-pysrc.html#index):

> Note that this pseudo dictionary will not support all the methods of
>   a   true Python dictionary, for example values() is not defined since
>   this   would require loading all of the records into memory at once.

If you use `SeqIO.to_dict` the error disappears, but you will probably run out of memory. I don't know about your specific task, but perhaps splitting the FASTA file in smaller chunks and using a full dictionary might solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I solve in an alternative way: share the index files of the large fasta file, and each progress fetch with the index.